# Responsive text background using span

Tags: css, responsive

I can't seem to find a solution for my text background to be responsive.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 65px;
}

.h1-marked {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  background-color: #9e2166;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 3px 100%, 100% 88%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 3px 100%, 100% 88%, 100% 0);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="h1-marked">Word een PuurZorgtalent</span><br>op Uitzendbasis!</h1>
```

I want the background to be as small as possible (depending on text) and still work responsive.

Comment: `font-size: 8vw;` will do the job. but it is not so much clean

Answer (score 0):

Maybe media queries will help?

You could use different clip path polygons depending on the shape the text takes in different viewport sizes.

```css
h1 {
        font-size: 65px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .h1-marked {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    .h1-marked {
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 4px;
        background-color: #9e2166;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 3px 100%, 100% 88%, 100% 0);
        clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 3px 100%, 100% 88%, 100% 0);
        display: inline-block;
    }
    @media (max-width: 760px) {
        .h1-marked {
            padding: 10px;
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 12%, 3px 100%, 77.18% 89.76%, 74.98% 44.83%, 48.33% 50.40%, 47.32% 13px);
            clip-path: polygon(0px 12%, 3px 100%, 77.18% 89.76%, 74.98% 44.83%, 48.33% 50.40%, 47.32% 13px);
        }
    }
```

```html
<h1><span class="h1-marked"><span class="test">Word een PuurZorgtalent</span></span><br>op Uitzendbasis!</h1>
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well. But in my tests the breakingpoint cutss off part of the text as well. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Then you can mix this solution with one that's changing font size depending on viewport width (mentioned above).